# What exactly triggers a re-compute()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive-programming

I have a very particular use case where I need to trigger a `computed()` reassessment. As far as I know, the recompute is triggered automatically once the state of a reactive variable used inside changes.

My question: is this the only case?

Consider the following pieces of code where the current (at compute time) date is returned. The value is set once and does not change. I need to have the value reassessed on a regular basis.

The following examples where a cyclic routine is running **inside** `computed()` do not change the computed value:

- an empty function is reassessed

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue'

const counter = computed(() => {
  setInterval(() => {}, 1000)
  return new Date()
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{counter}}</h1>
</template>
```

- a standard variable is recomputed

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue'

const counter = computed(() => {
  let u = 0
  setInterval(() => {u++; console.log(u)}, 1000)
  return new Date()
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{counter}}</h1>
</template>
```

- a reactive variable is recomputed

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

const counter = computed(() => {
  const u = ref(0)
  setInterval(() => {u.value++}, 1000)
  return new Date()
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{counter}}</h1>
</template>
```

When a reactive variable is changed **outside** of the function the recompute happens:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

const u = ref(0)
const counter = computed(() => {
  u.value;
  return new Date()
})
setInterval(() => {u.value++; console.log(u.value)}, 1000)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{counter}}</h1>
</template>
```

**My question (more precisely): is there a way to have the `setInterval()` run inside the computed() function? Or in other words: what exactly triggers a recompute?**

*Note: I know that this is a weird case and that I could have a reactive variable recomputed inside a `setInterval()` based on some function. Besides the fact that it is easier for me to do it this way, it is an opportunity for me to learn details about the reactivity cycle.*

Comment: It's incorrect to put setInterval inside of computed, end of the story. "easier for me" means that you try to do fundamentally wrong thing. It's *synchronous* access of `.value` that triggers the reactivity, it's all there https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html

Comment: @EstusFlask: Thank you, adding a synchronous access helped. When you say *It's incorrect to put setInterval inside of computed, end of the story.*, why is it so? Is there a mention of that in the docs somewhere? (I appreciate that despite the "end of story" you still provided an answer to the actual question)

Comment: I'm not sure if this sort of misuse mentioned explicitly but this is against the purpose of a computed, to compute a value from another value. Only the last snippet is acceptable but it's a hack, because it doesn't compute a value from another value. A computed is generally not supposed to contain side effects. For side effects a watcher is the way to go, especially for async ones like in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html), In order for the reactivity of a computed property to be triggered, reactive data needs to be (synchronously) accessed inside computed function, this allows it to be tracked for changes. This happens in the case of the last snippet, `u.value` is read in the body of computed function. There's no way how reactivity could be implemented in other snippets in JavaScript, a framework couldn't track the changes inside `setInterval` callback and associate them with `counter`.

The purpose of computed property is to compute a property from other reactive data, as the name suggests. The last snippet is workable but misuses a computed, because `new Data` doesn't derive from reactive data the computed depends on (`u`). It's generally a [bad practice for a computed to contain side effects](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#getters-should-be-side-effect-free). Asynchronous side effects are useless for the way a computed works and cause more potential problems, in this case `setInterval` isn't cleaned up properly and may result in undesired behaviour and memory leaks.

In rare cases this rule can be ignored, e.g. the implementation of translation function where the change in a locale is supposed to recalculate localized value:

```
const i18n = reactive({
  locale: ref('en'),
  translate: computed(() => {
    i18n.locale; // not a no-op, needed to track the changes
    return str => i18n.messages[i18n.locale][str];
  }),
  messages: { ... },
});
```

A computed is a more concise and efficient way to do what a watcher does. A long as a case doesn't fit the regular usage of a computed, this means this is a case for a watcher, this applies to all cases that involve side effects. In this case a proper way to write with a watcher would be:

```
const u = ref(0)
const counter = ref();

// needs to be cleaned up, goes to onMounted for SSR compat
setInterval(() => {u.value++}, 1000)

watch(u, () => {
  counter.value = new Date();
}, { immediate: true });
```

In this case a watcher is redundant, as the same result could be achieved with:

```
setInterval(() => {counter.value = new Date()}, 1000)
```